# How can I dynamically refer to a variable in Python

Tags: python

Behold my simple class:

```
import sys

class Foo(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.frontend_attrs = ['name','ip_address','mode','port','max_conn']
    self.backend_attrs  = ['name','balance_method','balance_mode']
```

The init method above creates two lists and I want to refer to them both dynamically:

```
def sanity_check_data(self):
  self.check_section('frontend')
  self.check_section('backend')

def check_section(self, section):
  # HERE IS THE DYNAMIC REFERENCE
  for attr in ("self.%s_attrs" % section):
    print attr
```

But when I do this, python complains about the call to `("self.%s_attrs" % section)`.

I've read about people using `get_attr` to find modules dynamically...

```
getattr(sys.modules[__name__], "%s_attrs" % section)()
```

Can this be done for dictionaries.

Comment: You want `getattr(self, '{}_attrs'.format(section))`

Comment: You shouldn't be keeping data in your variable names at all, really. That's just asking for trouble. You should keep those two dictionaries in another structure, maybe even another dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for I think is [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr). Something like this:

```
def check_section(self, section):
    for attr in getattr(self, '%s_attrs' % section):
        print attr
```

Although with that specific case, you might be better off with a dict, just to keep things simple:

```
class Foo(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.my_attrs = {
      'frontend': ['name','ip_address','mode','port','max_conn'],
      'backend': ['name','balance_method','balance_mode'],
    }

  def sanity_check_data(self):
    self.check_section('frontend')
    self.check_section('backend')

  def check_section(self, section):
    # maybe use self.my_attrs.get(section) and add some error handling?
    my_attrs = self.my_attrs[section]
    for attr in my_attrs:
      print attr
```

Comment: Glad to help! If you click on the check icon next to the counter, then it will mark the question as solved with that particular answer.